# Random and graphics too long code

Tags: java, random, graphics, rectangles

I want to create a random number, then create 9 rectangles but one of them will be in a different color, the one with the different color will be according to the random number came out, so I have done it but the code is too long, how can I make it shorter?

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    rand = new Random();
    n = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
    if (n == 1) {
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        rec1 = new Rectangle(10, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec1.getX(), (int) rec1.getY(),
                (int) rec1.getWidth(), (int) rec1.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        rec2 = new Rectangle(70, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec2.getX(), (int) rec2.getY(),
                (int) rec2.getWidth(), (int) rec2.getHeight());
        rec3 = new Rectangle(130, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec3.getX(), (int) rec3.getY(),
                (int) rec3.getWidth(), (int) rec3.getHeight());
        rec4 = new Rectangle(10, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec4.getX(), (int) rec4.getY(),
                (int) rec4.getWidth(), (int) rec4.getHeight());
        rec5 = new Rectangle(70, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec5.getX(), (int) rec5.getY(),
                (int) rec5.getWidth(), (int) rec5.getHeight());
        rec6 = new Rectangle(130, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec6.getX(), (int) rec6.getY(),
                (int) rec6.getWidth(), (int) rec6.getHeight());
        rec7 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec7.getX(), (int) rec7.getY(),
                (int) rec7.getWidth(), (int) rec7.getHeight());
        rec8 = new Rectangle(70, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec8.getX(), (int) rec8.getY(),
                (int) rec8.getWidth(), (int) rec8.getHeight());
        rec9 = new Rectangle(130, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec9.getX(), (int) rec9.getY(),
                (int) rec9.getWidth(), (int) rec9.getHeight());
    } else if (n == 2) {
        rec1 = new Rectangle(10, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec1.getX(), (int) rec1.getY(),
                (int) rec1.getWidth(), (int) rec1.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        rec2 = new Rectangle(70, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec2.getX(), (int) rec2.getY(),
                (int) rec2.getWidth(), (int) rec2.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        rec3 = new Rectangle(130, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec3.getX(), (int) rec3.getY(),
                (int) rec3.getWidth(), (int) rec3.getHeight());
        rec4 = new Rectangle(10, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec4.getX(), (int) rec4.getY(),
                (int) rec4.getWidth(), (int) rec4.getHeight());
        rec5 = new Rectangle(70, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec5.getX(), (int) rec5.getY(),
                (int) rec5.getWidth(), (int) rec5.getHeight());
        rec6 = new Rectangle(130, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec6.getX(), (int) rec6.getY(),
                (int) rec6.getWidth(), (int) rec6.getHeight());
        rec7 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec7.getX(), (int) rec7.getY(),
                (int) rec7.getWidth(), (int) rec7.getHeight());
        rec8 = new Rectangle(70, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec8.getX(), (int) rec8.getY(),
                (int) rec8.getWidth(), (int) rec8.getHeight());
        rec9 = new Rectangle(130, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec9.getX(), (int) rec9.getY(),
                (int) rec9.getWidth(), (int) rec9.getHeight());
    } else if (n == 3) {
        rec1 = new Rectangle(10, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec1.getX(), (int) rec1.getY(),
                (int) rec1.getWidth(), (int) rec1.getHeight());
        rec2 = new Rectangle(70, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec2.getX(), (int) rec2.getY(),
                (int) rec2.getWidth(), (int) rec2.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        rec3 = new Rectangle(130, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec3.getX(), (int) rec3.getY(),
                (int) rec3.getWidth(), (int) rec3.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        rec4 = new Rectangle(10, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec4.getX(), (int) rec4.getY(),
                (int) rec4.getWidth(), (int) rec4.getHeight());
        rec5 = new Rectangle(70, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec5.getX(), (int) rec5.getY(),
                (int) rec5.getWidth(), (int) rec5.getHeight());
        rec6 = new Rectangle(130, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec6.getX(), (int) rec6.getY(),
                (int) rec6.getWidth(), (int) rec6.getHeight());
        rec7 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec7.getX(), (int) rec7.getY(),
                (int) rec7.getWidth(), (int) rec7.getHeight());
        rec8 = new Rectangle(70, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec8.getX(), (int) rec8.getY(),
                (int) rec8.getWidth(), (int) rec8.getHeight());
        rec9 = new Rectangle(130, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec9.getX(), (int) rec9.getY(),
                (int) rec9.getWidth(), (int) rec9.getHeight());
    } else if (n == 4) {
        rec1 = new Rectangle(10, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec1.getX(), (int) rec1.getY(),
                (int) rec1.getWidth(), (int) rec1.getHeight());
        rec2 = new Rectangle(70, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec2.getX(), (int) rec2.getY(),
                (int) rec2.getWidth(), (int) rec2.getHeight());
        rec3 = new Rectangle(130, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec3.getX(), (int) rec3.getY(),
                (int) rec3.getWidth(), (int) rec3.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        rec4 = new Rectangle(10, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec4.getX(), (int) rec4.getY(),
                (int) rec4.getWidth(), (int) rec4.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        rec5 = new Rectangle(70, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec5.getX(), (int) rec5.getY(),
                (int) rec5.getWidth(), (int) rec5.getHeight());
        rec6 = new Rectangle(130, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec6.getX(), (int) rec6.getY(),
                (int) rec6.getWidth(), (int) rec6.getHeight());
        rec7 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec7.getX(), (int) rec7.getY(),
                (int) rec7.getWidth(), (int) rec7.getHeight());
        rec8 = new Rectangle(70, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec8.getX(), (int) rec8.getY(),
                (int) rec8.getWidth(), (int) rec8.getHeight());
        rec9 = new Rectangle(130, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec9.getX(), (int) rec9.getY(),
                (int) rec9.getWidth(), (int) rec9.getHeight());
    } else if (n == 5) {
        rec1 = new Rectangle(10, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec1.getX(), (int) rec1.getY(),
                (int) rec1.getWidth(), (int) rec1.getHeight());
        rec2 = new Rectangle(70, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec2.getX(), (int) rec2.getY(),
                (int) rec2.getWidth(), (int) rec2.getHeight());
        rec3 = new Rectangle(130, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec3.getX(), (int) rec3.getY(),
                (int) rec3.getWidth(), (int) rec3.getHeight());
        rec4 = new Rectangle(10, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec4.getX(), (int) rec4.getY(),
                (int) rec4.getWidth(), (int) rec4.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        rec5 = new Rectangle(70, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec5.getX(), (int) rec5.getY(),
                (int) rec5.getWidth(), (int) rec5.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        rec6 = new Rectangle(130, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec6.getX(), (int) rec6.getY(),
                (int) rec6.getWidth(), (int) rec6.getHeight());
        rec7 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec7.getX(), (int) rec7.getY(),
                (int) rec7.getWidth(), (int) rec7.getHeight());
        rec8 = new Rectangle(70, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec8.getX(), (int) rec8.getY(),
                (int) rec8.getWidth(), (int) rec8.getHeight());
        rec9 = new Rectangle(130, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec9.getX(), (int) rec9.getY(),
                (int) rec9.getWidth(), (int) rec9.getHeight());
    } else if (n == 6) {
        rec1 = new Rectangle(10, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec1.getX(), (int) rec1.getY(),
                (int) rec1.getWidth(), (int) rec1.getHeight());
        rec2 = new Rectangle(70, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec2.getX(), (int) rec2.getY(),
                (int) rec2.getWidth(), (int) rec2.getHeight());
        rec3 = new Rectangle(130, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec3.getX(), (int) rec3.getY(),
                (int) rec3.getWidth(), (int) rec3.getHeight());
        rec4 = new Rectangle(10, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec4.getX(), (int) rec4.getY(),
                (int) rec4.getWidth(), (int) rec4.getHeight());
        rec5 = new Rectangle(70, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec5.getX(), (int) rec5.getY(),
                (int) rec5.getWidth(), (int) rec5.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        rec6 = new Rectangle(130, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec6.getX(), (int) rec6.getY(),
                (int) rec6.getWidth(), (int) rec6.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        rec7 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec7.getX(), (int) rec7.getY(),
                (int) rec7.getWidth(), (int) rec7.getHeight());
        rec8 = new Rectangle(70, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec8.getX(), (int) rec8.getY(),
                (int) rec8.getWidth(), (int) rec8.getHeight());
        rec9 = new Rectangle(130, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec9.getX(), (int) rec9.getY(),
                (int) rec9.getWidth(), (int) rec9.getHeight());
    } else if (n == 7) {
        rec1 = new Rectangle(10, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec1.getX(), (int) rec1.getY(),
                (int) rec1.getWidth(), (int) rec1.getHeight());
        rec2 = new Rectangle(70, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec2.getX(), (int) rec2.getY(),
                (int) rec2.getWidth(), (int) rec2.getHeight());
        rec3 = new Rectangle(130, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec3.getX(), (int) rec3.getY(),
                (int) rec3.getWidth(), (int) rec3.getHeight());
        rec4 = new Rectangle(10, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec4.getX(), (int) rec4.getY(),
                (int) rec4.getWidth(), (int) rec4.getHeight());
        rec5 = new Rectangle(70, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec5.getX(), (int) rec5.getY(),
                (int) rec5.getWidth(), (int) rec5.getHeight());
        rec6 = new Rectangle(130, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec6.getX(), (int) rec6.getY(),
                (int) rec6.getWidth(), (int) rec6.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        rec7 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec7.getX(), (int) rec7.getY(),
                (int) rec7.getWidth(), (int) rec7.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        rec8 = new Rectangle(70, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec8.getX(), (int) rec8.getY(),
                (int) rec8.getWidth(), (int) rec8.getHeight());
        rec9 = new Rectangle(130, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec9.getX(), (int) rec9.getY(),
                (int) rec9.getWidth(), (int) rec9.getHeight());
    } else if (n == 8) {
        rec1 = new Rectangle(10, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec1.getX(), (int) rec1.getY(),
                (int) rec1.getWidth(), (int) rec1.getHeight());
        rec2 = new Rectangle(70, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec2.getX(), (int) rec2.getY(),
                (int) rec2.getWidth(), (int) rec2.getHeight());
        rec3 = new Rectangle(130, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec3.getX(), (int) rec3.getY(),
                (int) rec3.getWidth(), (int) rec3.getHeight());
        rec4 = new Rectangle(10, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec4.getX(), (int) rec4.getY(),
                (int) rec4.getWidth(), (int) rec4.getHeight());
        rec5 = new Rectangle(70, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec5.getX(), (int) rec5.getY(),
                (int) rec5.getWidth(), (int) rec5.getHeight());
        rec6 = new Rectangle(130, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec6.getX(), (int) rec6.getY(),
                (int) rec6.getWidth(), (int) rec6.getHeight());
        rec7 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec7.getX(), (int) rec7.getY(),
                (int) rec7.getWidth(), (int) rec7.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        rec8 = new Rectangle(70, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec8.getX(), (int) rec8.getY(),
                (int) rec8.getWidth(), (int) rec8.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        rec9 = new Rectangle(130, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec9.getX(), (int) rec9.getY(),
                (int) rec9.getWidth(), (int) rec9.getHeight());
    } else {
        rec1 = new Rectangle(10, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec1.getX(), (int) rec1.getY(),
                (int) rec1.getWidth(), (int) rec1.getHeight());
        rec2 = new Rectangle(70, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec2.getX(), (int) rec2.getY(),
                (int) rec2.getWidth(), (int) rec2.getHeight());
        rec3 = new Rectangle(130, 130, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec3.getX(), (int) rec3.getY(),
                (int) rec3.getWidth(), (int) rec3.getHeight());
        rec4 = new Rectangle(10, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec4.getX(), (int) rec4.getY(),
                (int) rec4.getWidth(), (int) rec4.getHeight());
        rec5 = new Rectangle(70, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec5.getX(), (int) rec5.getY(),
                (int) rec5.getWidth(), (int) rec5.getHeight());
        rec6 = new Rectangle(130, 70, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec6.getX(), (int) rec6.getY(),
                (int) rec6.getWidth(), (int) rec6.getHeight());
        rec7 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec7.getX(), (int) rec7.getY(),
                (int) rec7.getWidth(), (int) rec7.getHeight());
        rec8 = new Rectangle(70, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec8.getX(), (int) rec8.getY(),
                (int) rec8.getWidth(), (int) rec8.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        rec9 = new Rectangle(130, 10, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect((int) rec9.getX(), (int) rec9.getY(),
                (int) rec9.getWidth(), (int) rec9.getHeight());
    }

}
```

New code::

```
private static void drawRectangle(Graphics g, int column, int row,
        Color color) {
    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillRect(column * 60 + 10, row * 60 + 10, 50, 50);
    n = rand.nextInt(9);
    for (row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
        for (column = 0; column < 3; column++) {
            drawRectangle(g, column, row,
                    n == row * 3 + column ? Color.LIGHT_GRAY
                            : Color.DARK_GRAY);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know about loops and arrays?

Comment: Create 8 rectangles. Afterwards check the random number. That way you are only creating one rectangle for any possible case. Or you can create 9 and just set the fill color for the case.

Comment: Do you actually need the `Rectangle` objects afterwards?

Comment: @JonSkeet I think it would be wise if we assume he might be using them later. He did put the effort in declaring them outside the scope.

Comment: @tobias_k not so much.. I am a beginner..

Comment: @JonSkeet I do need it , it is for a game :) , I need them after to change their places..

Comment: @user3731180: It's not clear what you mean by that. If you mean you'll need to change the color of different rectangles (e.g. with the light gray square moving around), you don't necessarily need `Rectangle` objects for that.

Comment: @JonSkeet Basicly, I need some object, one in an other color, and all I need is moving their places.. (rec1.setBounds) .. what can I use except rectangles?

Comment: @user3731180: What makes you think you need an object for that at all? Changing the bounds of the rectangle won't redraw it - that's just what `g.fillRect()` does. See my answer for an example of a method to just draw a rectangle at the right place - consider redrawing the whole board with the new appropriate rectangles whenever you need to.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is belongs on CodeReview

Answer (score 4):

I would start off by writing a helper method:

```
private static void drawRectangle(Graphics g, int column, int row, Color color) {
    // TODO: Remember the previous color of g and reset it afterwards?
    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillRect(column * 60 + 10, row * 60 + 10, 50, 50);
}
```

Then in the code that needs to draw the rectangles (e.g. where the code in your question is) use a nested loop to draw all 9 rectangles, working out the color of each rectangle based on the value of `n`:

```
// It's simpler to use n being 0 to 8, if that's okay with the rest of your code.
n = rand.nextInt(9);
for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++) {
        drawRectangle(g, column, row,
            n == row * 3 + column ? Color.LIGHT_GRAY : Color.DARK_GRAY);
    }
}
```

That's assuming you don't actually need the `Rectangle` objects at all. If you do, you'd change the `drawRectangle` method to create and return a `Rectangle`, and then either have a `Rectangle[]`, a `List<Rectangle>` or possibly a `Rectangle[][]` depending on what you want to do with them. I would strongly recommend that you *don't* just have 9 separate variables.

Comment: I haven't understand it :\ what is the int row and int column, what is the color :( can you please make an explanation..?

Comment: Can you see the new code in the edit.. I basicly copied yours but it gives an empty JFrame..

Comment: @user3731180: You've misunderstood - `drawRectangle` is *just* that small piece of code - then from wherever you've got your *current* long code, you put the code which *calls* `drawRectangle`. That's where `row` and `column` come from (the loop) and the color - selected based on `n`.